# UINavigationBar not hide in iPad but Hides in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, uinavigationbar, xcode4.5

Hello guys I am making a Universal app and the behavior of `UINavigationBar` on `iPad` for a `ViewController` class not working.I googling a lot and also try the many solutions but did't work for me.The `setHidden` property of `UINavigationBar` not working on iPad but it working fine in iPhone. `UINavigationBar` not hide in iPad I use the following way to make it hide but all these way failed in iPad but these working in iPhone:-

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

And one more point when I goes from this 1st `viewController` to another 2nd `ViewController` and when I pop from 2nd `ViewController` then it goes to different `ViewController` class not to 1st `ViewController` class.

[Here's the pastebin link to the ViewController Code:-](http://pastebin.com/9v0ERJcz)

Comment: By default Universal App template has conditional case for iPhone & iPad. iPhone has `UINavigationController` while iPad has `UISplitViewController`

Comment: @hpiOSCoder coder if i got a satisfactory solution then i accept.i cant accept the fake answer which are logic less and dont have any connection with the problem. i am sorry i cant..

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i am using UINavigationController not UISplitViewController!!!!

Comment: check your method because it may be you call it two times.

Comment: you are right i am calling two methods on a single button which created problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, are you sure you are suing a UINavigationController, not a UISplitViewController (as Shivan rightfully points out)? Also, are you sure your are running your hide action from your main tread ?

In any case, I found this, that might help you;

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad )
{
    CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y < 0 ?
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height
    :   rect.origin.y - rect.size.height;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
else 
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:shouldHide animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I set up a small test myself, and it works. Are you sure you don't have any other code manipulating with the header bar ? and are you sure you are running the code from the right place ?

Comment: yes i am calling it in viewDidLoad method. And my navigation is  HomeVwcntrllr-->1stviewCntrllr(navigationBar Problem)..

Comment: And Nils in last lines of my question when i goes two times in to 2nd ViewController then PoP to 1stviewCntrllr(navigationBar Problem) then navigationBar didnot appear it Hides after that...

Comment: try `viewWillAppear:` method to hide the navigationBar

Comment: @Wolvorin  and a message appear in console :- Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UITabBarController: 0x9eadd70>. was it mean.

Comment: this means that you are try to do animation on UITabBarController not on UINavigationController

Comment: @Wolvorin not i am not dealing with UITabBarController You can check my code on pastebin link:-http://pastebin.com/9v0ERJcz

Comment: ok what I understands from the code is (1) Just remove the line `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` from the init method (the first one). (2) Then the line `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` in `viewDidLoad` shift it to the `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method :)

Comment: @Wolvorin thanks for giving your valuble time to my question i did a silly mistake i call two method on a button click which is created problem.

Comment: @NilsMunch thanks for giving us a different way to hide navigationBar.i did a silly mistake i call two method on a single button click which is created problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21373/discussion-between-ravi-sharma-and-wolvorin)